# Xamarin.Forms - change device orientation based on device resolution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

is there any chance to force change screen orientation based device screen resolution?

Have app for tablets, but I want to run app on mobile device too. I have a few pages, where I need to change orientation to landscape on phone, because then is my listview a litle bit messy.

Thank you for any advice and I apologize for the bad English :)

Comment: Are you targeting on both ios and android?

Comment: Yes, is there any chance ?

Comment: hi marek can you go through this https://www.appliedcodelog.com/2017/05/force-landscape-or-portrait-for-single.html

Comment: @marek Hi ,have you solve this ? If answer be helpful , remember to mark that when you  have time :-）

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)** to achieve that .

For example , when navigating from **MainPage** to **PageTwo** in Forms , the content page of `PageTwo` as follow :

```
public partial class PageTwo : ContentPage
{
    public PageTwo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "allowLandScape");
    }
    //during page close setting back to portrait
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "quitLandScape");
    }
}
```

In **Android** , need to modify MainActivity as follow :

```
[Activity(Label = "ForceOrientation", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    //allowing the device to change the screen orientation based on the rotation

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PageTwo>(this, "allowLandScape", sender =>
        {
            RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
        });

        //during page close setting back to portrait
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PageTwo>(this, "quitLandScape", sender =>
        {
            RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        });
    }
}
```

In **iOS** , we need to create a **PageTwoRenderer** as follow :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PageTwo), typeof(PageTwoRenderer))]
namespace ForceOrientation.iOS
{
    public class PageTwoRenderer : PageRenderer
    {

        public PageTwoRenderer()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PageTwo>(this, "allowLandScape", sender =>
            {
                UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(NSNumber.FromNInt((int)(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft)), new NSString("orientation"));
            });

            //during page close setting back to portrait
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PageTwo>(this, "quitLandScape", sender =>
            {
                UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(NSNumber.FromNInt((int)(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait)), new NSString("orientation"));
            });
        }
      
    }
}
```

==============================Update=============================

We can use **[Xamarin.Essentials: Device Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?tabs=ios#using-deviceinfo)**  to check whether the device is `Phone` , `Tablet` or *other devices* .

**DeviceInfo.Idiom** correlates a constant string that maps to the type of device the application is running on. The values can be checked with the DeviceIdiom struct:

- **DeviceIdiom.Phone** – Phone
- **DeviceIdiom.Tablet** – Tablet
- **DeviceIdiom.Desktop** – Desktop
- **DeviceIdiom.TV** – TV
- **DeviceIdiom.Watch** – Watch
- **DeviceIdiom.Unknown** – Unknown

Modiied **PageTwo** as follow :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var idiom = DeviceInfo.Idiom;

    if (idiom == DeviceIdiom.Phone)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "allowLandScape");
    }
       
}
//during page close setting back to portrait
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    var idiom = DeviceInfo.Idiom;

    if (idiom == DeviceIdiom.Phone)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "quitLandScape");
    }
       
}
```

Comment: I think he need to do this if the device is phone only.

Comment: @junior-jiang-msft I need it only for phone or device with smaller screen size. On tablet is everything ok.

Comment: @marek Okey , you can use `DeviceInfo.Idiom` to check which the device is phone or tablet .I will update the answer .

Answer (score 1):

You can force set orientation on these few pages

```
// on IOS -> AppDelegate.cs

public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
{
    if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ) {
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
}

// and on Android -> MainActivity.cs do the same if else in here

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)       
{
    if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
    {
        RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape; 
    }
    else
    {
        RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    }
```

}

You can check about Device class more in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device#deviceidiom

Comment: @marek Hi , if answer be helpful , remember to mark that when you have time. :-)